# Create case records from report or Spreadsheet?

Tags: reporting, case, email2case

Is there way to create automatic case records in salesforce? We have requirement where user has to manually create case by looking at the spreadsheet date and they are very identical records. As there are so many records needs to be created its lot time consuming. Is there any auto process that fetch data from spreadsheet or salesforce report and create case ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use any of data loader tools.

There is the Apex Data Loader:

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Data_Loader

The Data Import Wizard(in browser):

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=data_import_wizard.htm
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewQuickStarts?id=000113376

And a number of 3rd party tools that are maybe a little more complicated then your use case.